# if he is slapped vs if he gets slapped

Tags: grammar

**I slap him.
He is slapped by me.
if he is slapped (by me).**

what is the different between `if he is slapped` **and** `if he gets Slapped`

**Are they both correct?**

Answer (score 1):

There's no real difference between "is slapped" and "gets slapped." Both are correct. I could easily switch "is" and "gets" in ashleedawg's examples and still get precisely the same meanings. "Gets slapped" is much more common, while "is slapped" sounds slightly more formal.

Answer (score 0):

They are very similar but, to me, usage depends on the context.

> If he gets slapped again, he's going to call the police.

**Definition:** hit (someone or something) with the palm of one's hand or a flat object.

The rest of the sentence would help to clarify.

I suppose with the other one, an alternate meaning:

> If he is slapped with a lawsuit again, he won't have any money left.

**Definition:** impose a fine or other penalty on.

Comment: I don't think the difference between ***to be slapped*** and ***to get slapped*** has anything to do with the semantic distinction you'rte making here. Both senses (essentially, *literal* and *metaphoric*) can be expressed using either verb.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that was the difference.  That's just the only examples I could think of off the top of my head!  "Gets slapped" sounds more natural to me than "is slapped" anyhow.